# Horizontal Menu vanishes in IE 8

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-8

I am revamping a basic site for a shelter in town. I'm trying to give them something nice but not flashy or hard for anyone to go in and maintain. I don't really want to code for IE 8 but I know elderly people and businesses are the last to update their browsers. Anyhow the menu vanishes in IE 8. I can hover over it and see the submenus which look wrong as well. I'm new to using the `.htc` file "hack" for rounded corners. I don't really want to give up but I'm having the worst time figuring out what I'm missing. In desperation I threw `behavior: url(border-radius.htc);` all over the place to see if it was a placement issue.

Link to practice site: http://www.seenaomi.net/care-corp/pracindex.shtml

I like what I ended up with. Hoping to be able to pull it off with IE8 any help would be greatly appreciated.

Compatibility view in IE 9 shows what I'm talking about. Madness.

HTML:

```
    <ul id="coolMenu">

        <li><a href="index.shtml">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">History</a>
            <ul class="noJS">
                <li><a href="facts.shtml">Facts</a></li>
                <li><a href="staff.shtml">Staff</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="programs.shtml">Programs</a>
            <ul class="noJS">
                <li><a href="gift.shtml">Donate</a></li>
                <li><a href="successstories.shtml">Successes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="publications.shtml">Events</a>
            <ul class="noJS">
                <li><a href="facility.shtml">Pictures</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="contact.shtml">Contact</a>
            <ul class="noJS">
                <li><a href="gift.shtml">Donate</a></li>
                <li><a href="Employment.shtml">Career</a></li>
                <li><a href="volunteer.shtml">Volunteer</a></li>
            </ul>    
        </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#coolMenu,
#coolMenu ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#coolMenu {
    float: right;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
    border-style: none;
}
#coolMenu > li { float: left }
#coolMenu li a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 2.1em 0 2.1em;
}
#coolMenu ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
#coolMenu ul li a { width: 60px }
#coolMenu li:hover ul.noJS { display: block }
/* Main menu
       ------------------------------------------*/
#coolMenu {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #5887B1;
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
}
#coolMenu > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#coolMenu > li:hover > a {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    color: #000000;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bolder;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
    border-style: none;
}
/* Submenu
       ------------------------------------------*/
#coolMenu ul {
    background-color: #CCC;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
    border-style: none;
}
#coolMenu ul li a {
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
    border-style: none;
}
#coolMenu ul li:hover a {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style: italic;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
    border-style: none;
}
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, you should have the `htc` only in the element on which you apply the rounded corners. If anything, you could try [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/).

Comment: I've been reading about pie, was hoping it was just something I wasn't seeing.

Comment: Well after more tinkering the menu is showing in IE8 but without rounded corners. Will try CSS3 PIE